# How To Check, In Java, If User Has Inputted Another Number:

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a Scientific Calculator and have ran into a problem.

Some functions of the Calculator only require 1 number (Like: sin, log, etc)
and others require 2 numbers (Like: +, -, etc).

I want to check whether the user has entered another number in the textfield, so it will execute the block of code that ***requires another number*** or it will go to the functions that ***don't require another number.***

Here is my Controller class (I am using JavaFX):

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Calculator_Controller implements Initializable {
    private String currentOperation;
    private double currentNumber;

    @FXML
    private TextField displayField = new TextField();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resources) {
       //TODO
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleOperator(ActionEvent event) {

        double newNumber = new Double(displayField.getText());
        switch (currentOperation) {
            case "+":
                currentNumber += newNumber;
                break;
            case "-":
                currentNumber -= newNumber;
                break;
            case "÷":
                currentNumber /= newNumber;
                break;
            case "×":
                currentNumber *= newNumber;
                break;
            case "xⁿ":
                currentNumber = Math.pow(currentNumber, newNumber);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }



            switch (currentOperation) {
                case "AC":
                    displayField.setText("");
                    break;
                case "n!":
                    currentNumber = factorial(currentNumber);
                    break;
                case "±":
                    currentNumber *= -1;
                    break;
                case "√":
                    currentNumber = Math.sqrt(currentNumber);
                    break;
                case "sin":
                    currentNumber = Math.sin(currentNumber);
                    break;
                case "cos":
                    currentNumber = Math.cos(currentNumber);
                    break;
                case "tan":
                    currentNumber = Math.tan(currentNumber);
                    break;
                case "x²":
                    currentNumber = Math.pow(currentNumber, 2);
                    break;
                case "10\uF006":
                    currentNumber = Math.pow(10, currentNumber);
                    break;
                case "log":
                    currentNumber = Math.log10(currentNumber);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        displayField.setText("" + currentNumber);
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleOperation(ActionEvent event) {
        currentNumber = new Double(displayField.getText());
        displayField.setText("");
        currentOperation = ((Button) event.getSource()).getText();
    }

     public double factorial(double n) {
         if(n <= 1)
             return 1;
         else
             return n * factorial(n - 1);
     }
}
```

I have removed the if-else but you can see where it should be. The first switch is for if() and the second switch is for else.

Thanks

P.S. Do I have to post the FXML file and Main class as well, for you guys to understand?

Comment: Huh? `@FXML
    private TextField displayField = new TextField();` Why create a `TextField`, if the `FXMLLoader` is supposed to assign the field's value?

Comment: Might have done that by mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this:

```
@FXML
public void handleOperator(ActionEvent event) {

    double newNumber = new Double(displayField.getText());
    switch (currentOperation) {
        case "+":
            currentNumber += newNumber;
            break;
        case "-":
            currentNumber -= newNumber;
            break;
        case "÷":
            currentNumber /= newNumber;
            break;
        case "×":
            currentNumber *= newNumber;
            break;
        case "xⁿ":
            currentNumber = Math.pow(currentNumber, newNumber);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }       
    displayField.setText("" + currentNumber);
}

@FXML
public void handleOperation(ActionEvent event) {
    currentNumber = new Double(displayField.getText());
    displayField.setText("");
    currentOperation = ((Button) event.getSource()).getText();
    switch (currentoperation) {
        case "AC":
            displayField.setText("");
            break;
        case "n!":
            currentNumber = factorial(currentNumber);
            break;
        case "±":
            currentNumber *= -1;
            break;
        case "√":
            currentNumber = Math.sqrt(currentNumber);
            break;
        case "sin":
            currentNumber = Math.sin(currentNumber);
            break;
        case "cos":
            currentNumber = Math.cos(currentNumber);
            break;
        case "tan":
            currentNumber = Math.tan(currentNumber);
            break;
        case "x²":
            currentNumber = Math.pow(currentNumber, 2);
            break;
        case "10\uF006":
            currentNumber = Math.pow(10, currentNumber);
            break;
        case "log":
            currentNumber = Math.log10(currentNumber);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    displayField.setText("" + currentNumber);
}
```

As you can see, I have moved the second `switch` to method, which handles operation, so it will be executed immediatelly when you use unary operation.

**EDIT** (Explanation)

When you move the second switch which calculates with one operands (unary) to method which handles operators, It will calculate the result when you press operator. When another operator (binary like +,-,*,/,% etc.) is pressed, switch wont calculate anything because there is no case for this types of operators. Binary operators is calcualted in your method how you wrote in question.

Note: not tested

Comment: Won't this result in the number getting printed even if the switch has no case...

Comment: you can replace `break` with `return` of course to avoid it @blazekick

Comment: Ok now not question specific... But how would one check if the user has entered another number?

Comment: Can you give me an example input, where it fails. @blazekick

Comment: Where is the exact problem, where it fails? when you press 5 then + etc. this is what I need to know ;) @blazekick

Comment: Ah... Sorry. Well if someone enters a number and wants to take the square root of it... then the program (Old Code) waits for the user to enter another number (even if I have clicked the Square root button) even though it is not required. 
This was due to me writing the statement: 
double newNumber = new Double(displayField.getText());

I want to bypass this statement if the user has clicked a button that does not require another number.

Comment: so I advice you in my answer to move switch with unary operators to method, which handles operators. so it will calculate after pressing operator button. If you try factorial, it wont work because of no assign, see my edit @blazekick

Comment: It works... I never said it didn't... But now I am not asking for this question specifically!

Comment: your statement `double newNumber = new Double(displayField.getText());` is good, one improvement can be `newNumber = newNumber * 10 + pressedKey;` Where you have to get `pressedKey`. You have to decide if you press the key from keyboard or with button. So your solution is much better ;). Sorry about my misunderstanding @blazekick

Comment: Not sure what you have done there.... Could you elaborate? Maybe with an example...

Comment: a  bit of explanation added to my answer @blazekick

Comment: OK, let me show you an example: you have already entered `1234` number, and now you want to press `5` to have `12345` number. So calculation will be `1234 * 10 + 5 = 12345`. Notice `10` is a base of numeric system you use. if you use binary system it will be `2` instead of `10` is it ok? @blazekick

Comment: Oh! Sorry... Thought pressedKey was something else... Thanks again!